# HTTP Request through java getting 401 response

Tags: java, http, http-post, httpurlconnection, http-get

I am trying to invoke a url through java using java.net.HttpURLConnection.
Below is the code.
I get 401 as response. The url is up.

```
// HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {


        String url = "http://10.10.200.151:8720/scheduler/stat.go?opt1=0&opt2=0&opt3=0";


        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
```

Is there something missing.

Comment: you might be missing proper headers in request

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status 401 indicate that the request requires authentication.
Perhaps this url need login, and the server check this by your cookie.